# Yii scopes with multi-table relations

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a model Order with one-to-many relationship to model Booking. Booking model, in turn, has a Connection model reference.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to scope out Order so that I only get the order that have bookings with Connection.isDefault value set to 0.

I may have many Bookings with the Order, so I need to look through the very first booking.

I feel this may not be achievable through the scope mechanism as I cannot pass Order/Booking primary keys through helper functions that can be used in scope. What is an alternative workaround here (if any) can you suggest?

The Order has a code for scopes:

    `public function scopes()
    {
        return array(
            'canView' => array(
                'with' => array(
                    'agency' => array(
                        'scopes' => array('myNetwork', 'myCompany' => 'OR')
                    )
                ),
            ),
            'canEdit' => array(
                'with' => array(
                    'agency' => array(
                        'scopes' => array('myNetwork', 'myCompany' => 'OR')
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }`

Comment: What's the negative marking for without a relevant explanation? Guess someone was just having a not so good day...

Comment: I did not negvote you, but you should have posted more info, like your table setup and and models. What you have written is almost impossible to read because there's no paragraphs/highlights either. I guess that must have played a role. Additionally, theoretical questions without explaining what you need, properly.. are bound to attract negvotes. You neither did mention if it is yii2 or yii1. lol..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using `CDbCriteria()`. add relation in `Bookings` table and `order` table.

The Bookings has a code for relation:

```
class Bookings extends CActiveRecord{

    public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.

        return array(
            'connectionRel' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'connection', 'booking_id', "condition" => 'isDefault = 0'),
        );
    }
}
```

The Order has a code for relation:

```
class Order extends CActiveRecord{

    public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.

        return array(
            'bookingsRel' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Bookings', 'booking_id', "with" => array('connectionRel')),
        );
    }
}
```

Find all order with booking relation :

```
Order::model()->with('bookingsRel')->findAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CDbCriteria()`. In `with` you can put relation and it there do again `with` (do some *CDbCriteriaCeption*). Try experimenting with other criteria params to fit your needs (like applying `$c->together = true;`)

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();
$c->with = [
    'bookings' => [
        'select' => false,
        'with' => [
            'connections' => [
                'select' => false,
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$c->addCondition('connections.isDefault = 0');

Order::model()->findAll($c);
```

Comment: I've added an example of how Orders are retrieved through the scopes function, please take a look, Justinas